# How to send mass notification to all users who is using my application

Tags: facebook, notifications

i am developing a Facebook application using PHP SDK. According to FB Developer docs, notifications can be send with this metdod;

POST /{recipient_userid}/notifications?access_token= … &template= … &href= …

but This Methot let me send notification to user with "{recipient_userid}" value. But i am trying to send all users a notification. How can i do it?

By finding all members who is using Application and in a loop one by one Notification sending?

thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't try this yet but i think facebook batch requests is the answer.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

I frequently have to send notification to all my app users (about 30000 users) and it takes too long. Sending by one by method can't let you send instant notification for all your users, if it works, then it will be also possible.